# How to change file in sharepoint library?

Tags: splistitem, file-upload, library, file

I have sharepoint documents library and I have wcf service from where i should download new version of document file on button click.

So i got next method:

```
   public void UpdateFile(SPListItem item, Stream newFileStream)
    {
       // How to update file?
    }
```

And i want to change existing sp item file to new one from stream.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per my knowledge you have to upload a template document with content type and metadata mapping.

so u can update the document. because document is generated based on your template.

below couple of links which helps you..

http://somnathmatere.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-to-programmatically-upload-document.html

http://www.sharepointbleached.com/2012/04/upload-document-programmatically.html

http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2011/02/using-document-templates-with-lists-and-content-types-in-sharepoint/

http://www.bfcnetworks.com/pull-sharepoint-2010-document-properties-into-word-quick-parts/

Comment: Those examples of adding new files. I want to leave existing SPListItem and just change or update file.